# Removing model from collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is a first attempt to making a backbone.js application. 
I have a contact which is my model and a list/collection of contacts.

The initial rendering and fetching of the list of contacts works fine.

Now I'm trying to remove a contact from the collection after a click event. 
It seems like I'm doing something wrong in the delete function of the ContactsView. 
When I console.log contacts at the end of that method, the this.contacts collection is not changed.

Any help is appreciated!

```
var Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
});

var Contacts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Contact,
    url: '/backbone/crm/contact'
});

var ContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.contacts = new Contacts();
        this.contacts.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        this.contacts.bind("change", this.render, this);
        this.contacts.bind("remove", this.render, this);
        this.contacts.fetch();
    },
    events: {
        "click .delete": "delete"
    },
    render: function() {
        $("#contacts tbody").replaceWith(
                                $("#contacts_tmpl").render({ 'contacts': this.contacts.toJSON() }));
    },
    delete: function(e) {
        var id = $(e.currentTarget).parents("tr").attr("id");
        var model = this.contacts.get(id);
        this.contacts.remove(model);
    }
});

var contactsView = new ContactsView({ el: $("#contacts")});
```

Comment: Seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/EFWGU/ . Is the element with the delete class a button or a link?

Comment: Indeed, there was something wrong with my render method. I've got one more question. So other response because I need more space for this.

Answer (score 0):

The model is effectively removed from the collection. But now I need to remove it server side to.

I've implemented this by doing:

```
var Contacts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Contact,
    url: '/backbone/crm/contact',
    initialize: function() {
        this.bind("remove", this.delete, this);
    },
    delete: function(model) {
        model.destroy();
    }
```

This works and sends the correct delete request, but I find this kind of awkward, to call a destroy method from the delete method.